# Installing and uninstalling Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributables on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, redistributable

I have a new Windows 10 and I want to install Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributables (2008 to 2022) but some of them can not be installed because they are located on a network location.

Also I can not uninstall them because either the location can not be specified or the same network location problem is shown.

Does anyone know what is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: If you go into C:\Windows\Installer\ add the "Subject" column to the view in Explorer, can you find the cached MSI file for the product you are trying to uninstall?  You should be able to Uninstall from there?

Comment: I do not have this folder; There is no such hidden or non-hidden folder in that location. @HelpingHand

Comment: Did you try typing c:\windows\installer into the address bar?

Comment: @HelpingHand C:\Windows\Installer\ and c:\windows\installer\ is the exact same path.

Comment: It will exist. Did you try just typing it into the address bar?

Comment: Thanks. I found the folder. Could you please explain that how should I find and uninstall the .msi files? @HelpingHand

Comment: Some of the folders here have two arrows pointing to each other on the top left side. Does this cause any problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the troubleshooter given in the Microsoft website solved the problem:
[Fix problems that block programs from being installed or removed](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed-cca7d1b6-65a9-3d98-426b-e9f927e1eb4d)

I uninstalled the problematic packages using this tool and then reinstall them.